# Prove existence of irreducible character.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a $p$-group, assume that $Z(G)$ (the set of all elements in $G$ that commutes with every element) is cyclic. Prove that it exists an irreducible character on $G$ such that $\ker \chi=1$.

I am looking for hints.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405752